# Possible inconsistency in a subspace of $l^∞$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Is it possible to have a suspace of  $l^∞$ in which every sequence has a finite number non-zero elements? if so, what would be the zero element of the space? This a problem of the book of Kreyszig (Problem 3 of section 2.3)

Comment: I think you already answeered your own question. It depends on whether finite number of non-zero elements allows to have all elements zero or not.

Answer (score 2):

Consider
$$
\ell^\infty_c := \{ x \in \ell^\infty \mid \exists N \in \mathbb{N} : x_n = 0 \; \forall n > N \}
$$
I claim this has the following properties:

- It's a subspace of $\ell^\infty$ (note this means they share the same vector space operations and identity elements - namely the same additive identity element!)
- It's not closed
- It's convex
- It's dense in $c_0$ (the set of all convergent sequences)
- Each element has at most $N$ non-zero elements for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$

Comment: $\ell^\infty_c$ is usually called $c_{00}$

Comment: @azarel ah ok good to know - I was introduced to it as "$\ell^\infty$ with compact support" ;P

Comment: It is dense in $c_0$, not in $c$.

Comment: @TomekKania right, I was thinking of how we can decompose $c$ into $\alpha \mathbf{1} + x$ where $x \in c_0$ and $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbf{1} = (1,1,1,\ldots)$.